# JSON_Encoded Value to be used in snother file

Tags: php, json

```
<?php

    echo $xml = file_get_contents("C:\wamp\www\Sample API\index.php");
    $result = json_decode($xml);
    var_dump ($result);

?>
```

Index.php:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $db=mysqli_select_db($conn,"login");
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM loginuser WHERE ID=11"  or die('MySQL Error.'); 
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while($data1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    $data[] = array('post'=>$data1);
    }

    $output = (array('posts' => $data));
    $out =json_encode($output);
    echo $out;

?>
```

i am trying to get output value of index.php in this file and i'm trying this given code but $result returns the null value.Where as the included file returns the desire value but in this case json_decode returns null value.

Comment: Please show us the full `index.php` file!

Comment: There is a edit button under your question! (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27999363/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can just change this:

```
echo $out;
```

to:

```
return $out;
```

And then you just can require the file into the other one like this:

```
$xml = require_once("C:\wamp\www\Sample API\index.php");
$result = json_decode($xml);
var_dump($result);
```